# Why is the mean for the F distribution not 1

Tags: statistics

A random variable $X$ has an F distribution. It has $p$ and $q$ degrees of freedom. I understand that $E(X)$ can be proven to be $\frac{q}{q-2}$ by integrating $xf(x)$. Why does the method below give an incorrect $E(X)$?

$U$ has the chi squared distribution with $p$ degrees of freedom. $V$ has the chi squared distribution with $q$ degrees of freedom.

$X=\frac{U/p}{V/q}$

$E(X)=\frac{E(U)/p}{E(V)/q} =\frac{p/p}{q/q}= 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected value of a quotient is not necessarily the quotient of the expected values.

Comment: Aren't U and V assumed to be independent of each other? Wouldn't that mean the expectation of quotients equal the quotient of expectations?

Comment: If $U$ and $V$ are independent, $E[U/V] = E[U] E[1/V]$.  But $E[1/V] \ne 1/E[V]$.

Comment: For a trivial example:  if $X \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p = 0.5)$, then $\Pr[X = 0] = \Pr[X = 1] = 1/2$, and $\operatorname{E}[X] = p = 0.5$, but quite clearly, $\operatorname{E}[1/X]$ is undefined, since $X = 0$ with positive probability hence $1/X$ is infinite with positive probability.